# Spring reactive webclient to Azure Kubernetes Service(AKS) is not working

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, spring-webflux

If i use a Spring reactive webclient to call to AKS service returning me 404 error. Whereas if I use the same piece of code to call to VMSS service, its returning me the data.

```
String aksUrl = "http://aksdomainname.net/aks-gateway/svc/catalog/"; //Dummy AKS Url service
//String vmSSUrl = "http://vmssdomainname.net/vmss-gateway/svc/catalog/"; //Dummy VMSS Url service

String uri = "/v1/ast"; //Dummy uri
final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 300_000)
                .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(300_000));
final ClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                                        .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                                                .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(100 * 1024 * 1024)).build())
                                        .baseUrl(aksUrl).clientConnector(connector)
                                        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                                        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).build();
final String resp = webClient.post().uri(uri).bodyValue(request).headers(h -> h.putAll(httpHeaders)).retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> {
                    log.error("Response: Failed {} took {} httpStatus {}", aksUrl, stopWatch, clientResponse.statusCode());
                    return Mono.empty();
                }).onStatus(HttpStatus::is2xxSuccessful, clientResponse -> {
                    log.info("Response: Success {} took {} httpStatus {}", aksUrl, stopWatch, clientResponse.statusCode());
                    return Mono.empty();
                }).bodyToMono(String.class).map(response -> {
                    log.trace("Response: {}", response);
                    log.info("    Took: {}", stopWatch);
                    return response;
                }).block();
```

Response: Failed http://aksdomainname.net/aks-gateway/svc/catalog/v1/ast took 0s 827ms httpStatus 404 NOT_FOUND

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** The same is working fine if I use RestClient